# Java change object atributes values

Tags: java

in this code
Why this prints >> 0 8  instead of >> 5 8 .
The method `doIt()` changes the number of Person p which is already allocated, but the int x is already allocated and is not changed in `doIt()`.
Can anyone give me an theoretic explanation? I'm trying to understand how it works.
Thanks.

```
class Person{
   int number=0;
}

class Student extends Person
{
    int studentNumber;
}

public class Prog{


    public void doIt(int x, Person p)
    {
        x=5;
        p.number=8;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Prog p = new Prog();
       p.test();

    }

    public void test()
    {
        int x=0;
        Person p = new Person();
        doIt(x,p);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(p.number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Java is always pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Primitives such as `int` are passed by value, so your `x` in `test` is never modified; it's always 0.  Only the local copy `x` in `doIt` is changed to `5`, but that value goes away when the method `doIt` ends.

There are two `x` variables in your program:

- The `x` in `test`: initialized to 0 and never changed.
- The `x` in `doIt`: initialized to 0, changed to 5, and never used.

The reference to your `Person` object is passed by value, but `doIt` *does* modify `number` in the original object, so it changes to `8`.

There are two `p` variables in your program:

- The `p` in `test`: initialized to a new `Person` object.  `number` is initialized to 0.
- The `p` in `doIt`: it refers to the *same* `Person` object as the `p` in `test`.  So when `doIt` changes `number` to `5`, it modifies the one and only `Person` object you have.

Comment: So in doIt x is a copy and p is the real object, because x is primitive and Person p isn't ?

Comment: Close.  In `doIt`, `x` is a copy of the `x` in `test`.  `p` is a copy too.  But it's a copy of the _reference_ to the object.  So both `p` variables, in `doIt` and in `test`, refer to the one and only `Person` object.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I'm more accustomed to c++, where i can specify de copys, references..

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types, like integers, are based by value instead of by data reference. By setting `x=0` in the method, that doesn't set the value of x in the test method to 0, because when x is passed to `doIt`, it is merely by value. Therefore, anything you do in the method isn't recorded. You would have to pass an object, like `Person` for the changes to occur.